# In IntelliJ, how do I set which commit File Status Highlights are based on?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, diff

JetBrains' webhelp for [File Status Highlights](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-status-highlights.html) says the colour of filenames in the Project tree, and of the margin in the editor, depend on whether the code has changed since the last *synchronisation*. What is a 'synchronisation', when the VCS is Git?

A file's 'changed' status doesn't seem to have much to do with the file's status in Git. Some files in the Git index are marked as 'changed' and some aren't, and some 'changed' files haven't even changed since the last commit! What's going on here? Right-clicking a project or file and selecting 'Synchronise' doesn't seem to change anything.

Exactly what makes IntelliJ think a file is 'changed', and how can I make this depend on whether it differs from a particular commit, like with the 'QuickDiff' feature in Eclipse?

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 13.1.2

Answer (score 0):

> What is a 'synchronisation', when the VCS is Git?

The last time you've pulled your changes from the repository. In other words, it shows you only the local changes.

> Exactly what makes IntelliJ think a file is 'changed', and how can I make this depend on whether it differs from a particular commit, like with the 'QuickDiff' feature in Eclipse?

Run `git status` in the terminal for the same directory, IntelliJ IDEA `Changes` | `Local` view should correspond to it.

Make sure the correct folder(s) is mapped to Git in `Settings` | `Version Control`.

> Right-clicking a project or file and selecting 'Synchronise' doesn't seem to change anything.

It's not related to Git. This action synchronizes external file system changes with the IDE if they were not detected automatically for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps there was a bug in the version I was using at the time I posted this question, where things got out of sync when I ran git at the command line, and not within the IDE. I think it's better now, but I'm not certain it doesn't still get out of sync sometimes. I'll keep an eye on it, and when I'm convinced it works correctly, I'll up-vote this answer.